# ImportError: No module named 'keras'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, keras

So basically, I am fairly new to programming and using python. I am trying to build an ANN model for which I have to use Tensor flow, Theano and Keras library. I have Anaconda 4.4.1 with Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10 x64 and I have installed these libraries by following method.

1. Create a new environment with Anaconda and Python 3.5:
   conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 anaconda
2. Activate the environment: 
   activate tensorflow
3. After this you can install Theano, TensorFlow and Keras:
   conda install theano,
   conda install mingw libpython,
   pip install tensorflow,
   pip install keras,
4. Update the packages:
   conda update --all

All these packages are installed correctly and I have check them with conda list.
However, when I am trying to import any of these 3 libraries (i.e. Tensor flow, Theano and Keras), it is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-3-c74e2bd4ca71>", line 1, in <module>
import keras
ImportError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: Sounds like you got the install right.  So i'm assuming you're running some py file from the command line or an editor?

Comment: which python interpreter are you using?

Comment: I was able to get Keras up and running using the steps listed at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47498448/896802).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217084/4275148) is how I usually install everything related to keras.

Comment: Since you are using iPython, checkout [my related issue in other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47702229/793367).

Answer (score 26):

Hi I have an solution try this if you are using `Anaconda-Navigator`

go to **Anaconda Environment** and search **keras package** and then **install**.

[image: install keras]

[image]

after install just type `import keras` in shell its working.

[image]

Comment: Strange... I'm not seeing Keras when searching in Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: Had the same problem on the same course:) Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried using keras documentation

**Install Keras from PyPI (recommended):**

> Note: These installation steps assume that you are on a Linux or Mac environment. If you are on Windows, you will need to remove sudo to run the commands below.

```
sudo pip install keras
```

If you are using a virtualenv, you may want to avoid using `sudo`:

```
pip install keras
```

from: https://keras.io/

Answer (score 9):

Now you need to have Tensorflow installed and then write, for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
 ...
```

Works for Tensorflow version: 2.4.1.

Or just type:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and see if your anaconda `site-packages` folder is in the list.

It should be something like `WHERE_YOU_INSTALLED_ANACONDA\anaconda3\envs\ENVIRONMENT_NAME\lib\python3.5\site-packages`

If the path setting is correct, then try listing the folder content, and see if Keras, TensorFlow and Theano are in this folder.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a very similar issue after switching computers and downloading the latest Anaconda, which comes with python 3.6. It was no problem to install python 3.5 in its own environment, and install keras to this environment, but `import keras`kept failing.

My inelegant solution (assuming you've already got tensorflow/theano/cntk working fine in your global environment)?

Move the keras folder installed to Anaconda3/envs//Lib/site-packages/keras to Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/keras. Now `import keras` gives a depreciation warning when run from a jupyter notebook launched via start menu, but it does work, and correctly returns the backend keras is running on.

Answer (score 3):

I spent the whole day to install Keras, tried all the available methods online, almost dying. But I still cannot import keras.

(1). After using conda install or pip install, and delete the "1 > null > 2&1" ... I activated in conda prompt by activating tensorflow_cpu, it doesn't work anyway.

(2). Then checked the keras, and print os.path(), no virtual environment inside. I got so braindead, just copied all the keras data file from virtual environment env, and put into the "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages".

(3). Now, tensorflow and keras work well.

Answer (score 2):

Click Update Index and then try searching for Keras again.

Comment: Please improve the quality of this post to include some explanation regarding why this is an appropriate solution and perhaps include some references.  This will improve the educational value of your post for the OP and future SO readers.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by running one of the following in the terminal according to [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras) website.

To install this package (keras) with conda run one of the following:

- conda install -c conda-forge keras conda install -c
- conda-forge/label/broken keras conda install -c
- conda-forge/label/cf201901 keras conda install -c
- conda-forge/label/cf202003 keras

If you never use conda before you can check [anaconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with:
conda 4.13.0
tensorflow 2.6.0

**Note:** We should not have to install Keras separately, as it ships with Tensorflow, starting with Tensorflow 2.0.

**Symptoms:**
Keras import (`from tensorflow import keras`) *does not* return an error, BUT any further reference to Keras *does* throw "ModuleNotFoundError", e.g. the following statements fail:

```
print(keras.__version__)
from keras import Sequential
```

I still don't have a direct solution for this, this is more of a **workaround**, but here it is:

1. Import ANY class from Keras JUST ONCE using full top-down import syntax AND instantiate it
2. Import Keras (now "for real")

E.g.:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
layer = Dense(10)
from tensorflow import keras
```

Now the following statements should work:

```
print(keras.__version__)
model = keras.models.Sequential()
```

This looks like some sort of lazy module loading gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A direct and simple way to fix it is as below,
#uninstall keras and tensorflow

```
pip uninstall keras
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

#Now install keras and tensorflow for required version with dependencies.

```
pip install keras==2.2.4
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
```

Always make sure that you install right version of tensorflow which supports that keras version as well, else you may end up in trouble again. By the way , the above fix worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A direct and simple way to fix it is as below, #uninstall keras and tensorflow

```
py -3 -m pip uninstall keras
py -3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow
```

#Now install keras and tensorflow for required version with dependencies.

```
py -3 -m pip install keras
py -3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

the above fix worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you ran `pip install keras` at the command line, ensure that you use the small letter **'k'** instead of the Capital Alphabet. I had a similar error message.

Answer (score 0):

These are some simple steps to install 'keras' simply using the Anaconda Navigator:

1. Launch Anaconda Navigator. Go to the Environments tab.
2. Select ‘Not installed’, and type in ‘tensorflow’.
3. Then, tick ‘tensorflow’ and do the same for ‘keras’.
4. Click on ‘Apply’. The pop-up window will appear, go ahead and apply.
   This may take several minutes.
5. Done.

This tutorial will guide you more graphically: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-tensorflow-and-keras-using-anaconda-navigator-without-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Remember to launch spyder in the environment or activate it in line command (conda activate [my_env]. afater that, execute your script python.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import keras library from its reference parent which means `import tensorflow.keras`