# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras' when using tensorflow 2.6

Tags: tensorflow

I created a new conda env with

```
conda create --name tf tensorflow=2.6
```

and tried to compile

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
```

resulting in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

```
conda install keras
```

doesn't change anything.
I could go with

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
```

but when I
pip install tensorflow-addons
and

```
from tensorflow_addons.seq2seq.sampler import TrainingSampler
```

I end up with the same error

uninstalling tensorflow, installing just keras and trying

```
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
```

results in the same error

my versions are

```
tensorflow = 2.6
keras = 2.6
tensorflow-adons = 0.14
```

Comment: try `from tensorflow.keras .models import Sequential`

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna I tried but I need to use tensorflow_addons. Read the full question

Comment: Please checkout these threads . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271344/importerror-no-module-named-keras        https://www.edureka.co/community/67388/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-keras

Comment: I faced the same problem. I had to downgrade tensorflow to 2.5 then it worked. The only command I used is `conda create --name tf tensorflow=2.5`, no need to install anything else.

Comment: @Gqqnbig turns out that I had 2 keras versions installed, one from tensorflow and one from tensorflow nightly. Would be wise to check your `conda list` and `pip list` for duplicate keras installations

Answer (score 0):

What turned out is that I had both keras and keras nightly installed, the problem got resolved after uninstalling keras-nightly. If anyone encounters this check your `conda list` and `pip list` for duplicate keras installations

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem so adding an anwser here in the hope of helping others.

I use anaconda to set up python environments for machine learning precisely to get away from dependency clashes. So I set up a new environment to use tensorflow-gpu (version 2.6). After setup, I had the same problem importing *keras* on my initial tests. I was surprised because my understanding was *keras* is included under tensorflow. I was disinclined to downgrade or upgrade since the conda tensorflow install with the CUDA backend took over 2.5 hours. So I simply installed *keras* as follows:

```
conda install keras
```

The install was short and sweet and seems to have fixed the issue. I now see *keras* in my env listing and the imports work...

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.keras.__version__)
2.6.0
```