# Keras importerror: dlopen

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So for some assignment about 3 weeks ago, I managed to run
`import keras`
perfectly without any issues. Come today, without having done any changes or modifications I run it but was met with

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users//opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tfe.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.soReferenced from: /Users//opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tfe.so
> Reason: tried: '/Users//opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../../_solib_darwin_x86_64/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_C_Upywrap_Utfe.so___Utensorflow/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (no such file),

With a longer string that continues on stating (no such file). I've tried the remedies on ([ImportError: No module named 'keras'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271344/importerror-no-module-named-keras#comment81953804_45271344)) but to no avail. They show up in anaconda packages and the exact same step just 3 weeks ago ran fine but now it's stopped running. Does anyone know why?

I'm on TensorFlow - 2.8.0

Comment: Can you please share the standalone code to replicate above issue? Did you upgraded Keras/Tensorflow version recently? Are you able to run `import tensorflow as tf`?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing Keras using the below line of code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Comment: I get a message that reads, "ImportError: cannot import name '_pywrap_tf2' from 'tensorflow.python.platform'"

Comment: Please provide some details like which OS, Platform and python, tensorflow version you are using? And , What are the steps have you followed to install tensorflow?

Comment: Nevermind - I just added Tensorflow and Keras via Anaconda to my base environment